# Loading Games onto DosBox

Tags: windows-7, dosbox

I downloaded an old 16 bit game and also downloaded DosBox.  I believe I have the right pieces, but I can't figure out how to open the game on DosBox.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry, first question here - my PC is running Windows 7. The game is Romance of the Three Kingdoms. When I click on the exe file, it returns this error box: "The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher."

This is frustrating, because I realize this already and am trying to load onto DosBox emulator. I created a shortcut that specified the exe. file but when I clicked that it told me the exe was Windows based. Not quite sure what to do.

Comment: Please edit the relevant information into your question (see the "edit" link under the tags) rather than posting comments.

Answer (score 5):

You need to mount the game's folder in DosBox.

From the [DOSBox Wiki](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Basic_Setup_and_Installation_of_DosBox):

> Z:>MOUNT C C:\OLDGAMES
>   Drive C mounted as local directory C:\OLDGAMES\

- **MOUNT**: Tells the program to mount a directory
- **C**: Tells the program what you want your new drive to be called (leaving it as C is fine)
- **C:\OLDGAMES**: This is the directory with your game that you want to set as the new drive for DOSBox.

From there just change to the drive you mounted, and run the game.

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

1. Open DOSBox and type the following command at the prompt:

   ```
   mount c c:\yourgamedirectory
   ```

(Replace `c:\yourgamedirectory` with the path to the directory where the game you wish to run is located on your hard drive.)

2. Type `c:` at the prompt and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after the drive has been successfully mounted to access the game's directory.
3. Type the name of the executable file at the prompt and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the game.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run exe **inside** of DosBox, not just click in Windows.
May be better use one of GUI Frontends for DosBox (http://www.dosbox.com/download.php?main=1)?